# I am having troubles with Python functions, can someone help me?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Goal: I am trying to create a program that can take in 10 numbers then spit out the 10 largest numbers.

I need all integers able to be inserted, then for the program to find the odds and see which of them are the biggest.

```
#Introduction
print ('Enter 10 odd numbers to see which is the greatest ')
#The big question
user_input = raw_input ('Enter a odd number ')
#Input function that only accepts intergers
numbers = []
while numbers < 11:
    try:
        numbers.append(int(raw_input(user_input)))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid number'
#Function that finds the highest odd and sees if it is odd
highest_odd = max(user_input) and user_input % 2 != 0
print 'The largest odd number was' + str(highest_odd)
```

Comment: If you want to take in 10 numbers, then spit out the 10 largest, you can just print your input.

Comment: _"I need all integers able to be inserted, then for the program to find the odds and see which of them are the biggest. Here is what I tried, but it's not working"_ What part is it not working on? Where do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

**What you need to fix:**

1. Check whether the **length** of the list `numbers` exceeds 9 or not. You can get the length of a list by using [len( )](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function. So, it should be : `while len(numbers) < 9:` .
2. You didn't append the first input to the list `numbers`.
3. The way you `find the highest odd` doesn't work. Check out the modification.

**To sum up, the code should be :**

```
#Introduction
print ('Enter 10 odd numbers to see which is the greatest ')

#The big question
user_input = int(raw_input('Enter an odd number '))

#Input that only accepts integers
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < 9:
    try:
        numbers.append(user_input)
        user_input = int(raw_input('Enter an odd number '))
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid number'

#Find the highest odd
highest_odd = max(i for i in numbers if i % 2)

print "The largest odd number was " + str(highest_odd)
```

**Sample :**

```
>>> Enter 10 odd numbers to see which is the greatest 
>>> Enter an odd number 3
>>> Enter an odd number 5
>>> Enter an odd number 1
>>> Enter an odd number 7
>>> Enter an odd number 6
>>> Enter an odd number 4
>>> Enter an odd number 1.3
Invalid number

>>> Enter an odd number 9
>>> Enter an odd number 4
>>> Enter an odd number 6
The largest odd number was 9
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not clarify, I need all integers able to be inserted, then for the program to find the odds and see which of them are the biggest. Here is what I tried, but it's not working -__-

Comment: @llija So from my example, what's the expected output you are trying to get ?